# Proof that $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$ converges to $1$

Tags: proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I'm looking for some verification of my proof. The problem is asking me to prove that the sequence $\{s_{n}\}$ defined by

$$s_{n} = \dfrac{1}{n(n + 1)}$$

converges to $1$.I thought it goes to $0$, but maybe I'm missing something. Here's the problem word-for-word:

**Problem**

Define the sequence $\{s_{n}\}$ by

$$s_{n} = \dfrac{1}{2 \cdot 1} + \dfrac{1}{3 \cdot 2} + \ldots + \dfrac{1}{(n + 1)(n)}$$ for every index $n$.

Prove that the limit as $n$ approaches infinity of $s_{n}$ equals $1$.

**My proof:**

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrarily chosen. Choose $M = \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$, and let $n \geq M$ be arbitrarily chosen. Then,

$$\left| \dfrac{1}{n(n + 1)} - 1 \right| < \left| \dfrac{1}{n(n + 1)}\right| < \left|\dfrac{1}{n}\right| = \dfrac{1}{n} < \epsilon.$$

(I was able to remove the absolute value because $n > 0 ,$ always.)

Equivalently, this means that

$$n > \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}.$$

Thus, choosing $M = \dfrac{1}{e}$ means that the above inequality always holds, which completes the proof.

**Updated Proof**

Ok, so I think I was actually supposed to prove

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n(n + 1)} = 1.$$

By applying partial fraction decomposition, I found that this summation equals

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n} - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n + 1}.$$

From here, I can clearly see that everything cancels out except for the $1$ term. But is it possible to show this using the definition of convergence?

Comment: But as $n$ grows, $s_n\to 0$.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same. Maybe I'm missing something in my interpretation. Let me copy the problem word for word.

Comment: Specifically, your claim that $\big \vert \frac 1{n(n+1)}-1\big \vert <\big \vert \frac 1{n(n+1)}\big \vert $ is false for large $n$.

Comment: The sum, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{n(n+1)}$ does indeed equal $1$.  Hint:  expand the summands by partial fractions.

Comment: Be careful with distributing infinite sums. This is the sum of terms like $\frac1n-\frac{1}{(n+1)}$, but the infinite sums of the individual pieces both diverge to infinity, so you cannot write things as a difference of infinite sums as in your final expression.

Comment: Be careful with the lower bound of your summation. If the lower bound is zero (as you have it written in your problem), then the summation is not well-defined. The first term will be $$\dfrac{1}{0(0+1)} = \dfrac{1}{0}$$ which is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$0\le s_{n} = \dfrac{1}{n(n + 1)}\le \frac1n\to 0$$

and

$$\sum_1^\infty s_{n} = \sum_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{n(n + 1)}=\sum_1^\infty \left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n + 1}\right) =1\color{red}{-\frac12+\frac12-\frac13+\frac13-\frac14+\frac14-}\ldots$$

note also that

$$S_k=\sum_1^k s_{n}=1-\frac1{k+1} \to 1$$

Comment: I also found this. Is there a way to do it using the definition of convergence?

Comment: @Hat To do that you should express the partial sum $S_k$ and show that $S_k\to 1$ as $k\to \infty$. But telescoping is a very good and rigorous argument.

Comment: @Hat Indeed we have $S_k=1-\frac1{k+1}$ and it easy to show that $S_k \to 1$.

Comment: How did you get that $S_{k} = 1 - \dfrac{1}{k + 1}$?

Comment: @Hat Always by telescoping argument but in that way we can make it more rigorous considering a partial sum and then taking the limit.

Comment: Figured it out, thanks!

Comment: @Hat Well done! You are welcome, Bye!

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong and it could no possibly be right since the limit of the sequence is $0$, not $1$. Perhaps that what you were asked to prove was that $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(n+1)}=1.$$

The error in your proof lies in the (false) inequality$$\left|\frac1{n(n+1)}-1\right|<\left|\frac1{n(n+1)}\right|.$$